# Create labels on pdf

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, extjs

i want to open PDF file in a iframe OR windows Extjs
and let user click to  add labels 
what scripts can i use ?
im coding with Extjs / php /mysql 
i use [fpdf/fpdfi](http://www.fpdf.org/) libraries to write on a PDF file 
any idea ?  help please

thank

Answer (score 2):

Simply pointing iframe to PDF file only works when user has allowed it's web browser to embed Adobe Reader (I'm not even sure that other PDF-readers support this at all). This might be the common configuration for IE users, but in other browsers and especially on other OS-es it's not as common.

Another option is to use a service that renders your PDF as web page. For example using google docs it's dead easy:

```
<iframe
  src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://yourdomain.com/file.pdf&embedded=true"
  style="width:600px; height:500px;"></iframe>
```